# Clojure Lein Figwheel Error - Luminus Project with Re-Frame

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, web-development-server

I'm trying to create a web app using Luminus.
I created a project with `lein new luminus my-app +reagent +sqlite`, didn't change any file, just tried to run figwheel to compile javascript with `lein figwheel` but got the following error:

```
Figwheel: Cutting some fruit, just a sec ...
Retrieving clj-time/clj-time/0.14.3/clj-time-0.14.3.pom from clojars
Retrieving joda-time/joda-time/2.9.9/joda-time-2.9.9.pom from central
Retrieving conman/conman/0.7.8/conman-0.7.8.pom from clojars
Retrieving org/clojure/java.jdbc/0.7.5/java.jdbc-0.7.5.pom from central
Retrieving org/clojure/tools.cli/0.3.6/tools.cli-0.3.6.pom from central
Retrieving joda-time/joda-time/2.9.9/joda-time-2.9.9.jar from central
Retrieving org/clojure/java.jdbc/0.7.5/java.jdbc-0.7.5.jar from central
Retrieving org/clojure/tools.cli/0.3.6/tools.cli-0.3.6.jar from central
Retrieving clj-time/clj-time/0.14.3/clj-time-0.14.3.jar from clojars
Retrieving conman/conman/0.7.8/conman-0.7.8.jar from clojars
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at clojure.main.<clinit>(main.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, compiling: (figwheel_sidecar/utils.clj:1:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7526)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:379)

(... Many more lines)
```

My `project.clj` `:dependencies` looks like this:

```
 :dependencies [[clj-time "0.14.3"]
             [cljs-ajax "0.7.3"]
             [compojure "1.6.0"]
             [conman "0.7.8"]
             [cprop "0.1.11"]
             [funcool/struct "1.2.0"]
             [luminus-immutant "0.2.4"]
             [luminus-migrations "0.5.0"]
             [luminus-nrepl "0.1.4"]
             [luminus/ring-ttl-session "0.3.2"]
             [markdown-clj "1.0.2"]
             [metosin/muuntaja "0.5.0"]
             [metosin/ring-http-response "0.9.0"]
             [mount "0.1.12"]
             [org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]
             [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.238" :scope "provided"]
             [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.3.6"]
             [org.clojure/tools.logging "0.4.0"]
             [org.webjars.bower/tether "1.4.3"]
             [org.webjars/bootstrap "4.0.0-2"]
             [org.webjars/font-awesome "5.0.9"]
             [org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc "3.21.0.1"]
             [re-frame "0.10.5"]
             [reagent "0.7.0"]
             [ring-webjars "0.2.0"]
             [ring/ring-core "1.6.3"]
             [ring/ring-defaults "0.3.1"]
             [secretary "1.2.3"]
             [selmer "1.11.7"]]
```

How can I get arround this error? Might Luminus be outdated? And if it is, how should I start to do web apps with Clojure?

Comment: seem it is a bug from new version of template, you can change the line in env/dev/clj/user.clj `[<<project-ns>>.test.db.core]` to `[<<project-ns>>.db.core]`. This should fix the issue.

Comment: @AlbertLai Unfortunately it doesn't work. It gives the following error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at clojure.main.<clinit>(main.java:20)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate potemkin/namespaces__init.class or potemkin/namespaces.clj on classpath., compiling:(ring/util/http_response.clj:1:1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the template to reference the correct namespace in `user`. If you're still seeing issues, a couple of things to check would be the JDK version (8+ is recommended), and whether you have any plugins in the `~/.lein/profiles.clj` file that  might cause conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

I have just gone through trying to get a ClojureScript project configured to work with both Figwheel and the Doo testing framework.  The code lives in this repo:

```
git@github.com:cloojure/cljs-base-project.git
```

It does not include any server-side stuff yet, but I'll be adding more.

If you are starting with CLJS stuff (as implied by the figwheel part of your question), you may wish to start here and then add in the bits for Ring, Luminous, etc.

Also, be sure to [check out `lein-ancient`](https://github.com/xsc/lein-ancient) to check for outdated versions of your dependencies.